# Avoid collision of 'type' key when both event and logstash input provide values

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to write a pipeline to load a file into logstash. My setup requires specifying the `type` field in the input section to [Run multiple independent logstash config files with input,filter and output](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/running-multiple-independent-logstash-config-files-with-input-filter-and-output/29757). Unfortunately the source data already contains the field `type` and it looks like the value from the source data is conflicting with the value provided from the input configuration.

The source data contains a json array like the following

```
[
  {"key1":"obj1", "type":"looks like a bad choose for a key name"},
  {"key1":"obj2", "type":"you can say that again"}
]
```

My pipeline looks like the following

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "cat /path/file_containing_above_json_array.txt"
    codec => "json"
    type => "typeSpecifiedInInput"
    interval => 3600
  }
}

output {
  if[type] == "typeSpecifiedInInput" { 
    stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
    }
  }
}
```

The output never gets called because `type` has been set to the value provided from the source data instead of the value provided from the input section.

How can I set up the input pipeline to avoid this conflict?

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new field in your input instead of reusing 'type'.  The exec{} input has [add_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html#plugins-inputs-exec-add_field) available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That worked. I updated the answer with the completed pipeline using your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Below is the final pipeline that uses `add_field` instead of `type`. A filter phase was added to clean up the document so that `type` field contains the expected value needed for writing into ElasticSearch ([class of similar documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html)). The `type` value from the original JSON document is perserved in the key `typeSpecifiedFromDoc`  The mutate step had to be broken into separate phases so that the replace would not affect `type` before its original value had been added as the new field `typeSpecifiedFromDoc`.

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "cat /path/file_containing_above_json_array.txt"
    codec => "json"
    add_field => ["msgType", "typeSpecifiedInInput"]
    interval => 3600
  }
}

filter {
  if[msgType] == "typeSpecifiedInInput" {
    mutate {
      add_field => ["typeSpecifiedFromDoc", "%{type}"]
    }
    mutate {
      replace => ["type", "%{msgType}"]
      remove_field => ["msgType"]
    }
  }
}

output {
  if[type] == "typeSpecifiedInInput" { 
    stdout {
      codec => rubydebug
    }
  }
}
```